# SSH connect to EC2 instance of natty operation timeout

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

Novice has been trying to ssh into ec2 for 5 hrs straight.  Could they make anymore unfriendly to newbies? Trying 4-5 different tutorials to no avail. I've saved cert and pk in 
.ec2 folder and keypair in .ssh folder. Too many variables here (port authorize needed?, ubuntu uni/multiverse needed?, syntax issue?). Any ideas guys?

```
ssh -v -v -i *****.pem ubuntu@ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [XX.XX.XX.XX] port 22.
debug1: connect to address XX-XX-XX-XX port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: It seems that the connection is timing out before it's even established - are you connecting to the correct host? Is it running? Does it have a reachable IP address? Is a SSH server installed? Is it running? Is there a firewall on the server? If yes, is is allowing outside access to port 22?

Comment: thx@Piskvor Think all ubuntu have same host syntax. Yes using public DNS. Dont know how to tell if SSH running or if firewall. And when i run ec2-authorize -p 22 or ec2-authorize-port 22 i get command fail.

Comment: Are you sure the instance is running? If you have setup an elastic IP, you need to connect via SSH to that new IP, not the public DNS. Also, is it allowed through the firewall on the EC2 control panel? See this:  http://cl.ly/6f8r

Comment: aws has bright green light saying its running.

Comment: yes. Big green button on aws says running.  When you connect via 'instance management' in aws console default address its points you to is public dns. as do other tutorials. tried ip or private dns just for kicks which didnt fix.how do i tell if allowed thru firewall? any suggestions guys?

Comment: changed port settings via ec2 security as per @deanpcmad Still not working

Comment: have you tried `ec2-user` instead of `ubuntu`

Comment: following these directions worked for me: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

Answer (score 10):

do you have the port opened in your security group ? - if not allow port 22 for the ip's from where you want to connect.

Comment: I had the same problem when using the 'default' security group. use quick-start-1 instead!

Answer (score 9):

As Paul says, the default security group blocks ssh. You can enable it under "Security & Groups".

[image: Enable SSH for the security group]

Also, this information is listed in the Amazon documentation at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/gsg/2006-06-26/running-an-instance.html

Answer (score 2):

As deanpcmad said:

> If you have setup an elastic IP, you need to connect via SSH to that new IP, not the public DNS.

So connect to:

```
ssh -i ~/.ec2/***.pem -v ubuntu@YOUR_ELASTIC_IP
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and The Dean Perry's answer worked for me.**If you setup an elastic IP, you need to connect via SSH to that new IP, not the public DNS.**